# JavaFx error: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm coding a card game using javaFX in intelliJ on macOS with M2.
I'm using maven and it compiles without any problem, but when I run it it gives me this error:

Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

and then:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx:0.0.6:run (default-cli) @ Spacca_Cardcard ---
[INFO] Toolchain in javafx-maven-plugin null
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null
    at org.example.LoginScene.<init>(LoginScene.java:48)
    at org.example.App.createLoginView(App.java:23)
    at org.example.App.start(App.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application org.example.App
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (  at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
at  at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316)
 org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75)
JavaFXRunMojo.java:105  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

this is my main app code:

package org.example;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;


public class App extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        createLoginView(null);

        primaryStage.setTitle("SPACCA");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void createLoginView(String fileCode) {
        LoginScene login = new LoginScene(fileCode);
        login.setOnLoginSuccess(() -> switchToHomeView());
        login.setOnGameStart(() -> switchToGameView(login.getGameCode()));
        login.setOnTournamentLobby(() -> switchToTournamentLobbyView(login.getGameCode()));
        login.setOnInstruction(() -> switchToInstructionView());
        login.setOnLeaderBoard(() -> switchToLeaderBoardView());

        primaryStage.setTitle("LOGIN - SPACCA");
        primaryStage.setScene(login.getScene());
    }

    private void createHomeView() {
        AdminScene adminScene = new AdminScene();
        adminScene.setOnLogoutHandle(() -> switchToLoginView(null));
        adminScene.setOnCreateGameHandle(() -> switchToGameSetupView(adminScene.getIsTournament()));
        adminScene.setOnUserSceneHandle(() -> switchToUserSceneView());

        primaryStage.setTitle("ADMIN - SPACCA");
        primaryStage.setScene(adminScene.getScene());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    private void createGameView(String gameCode) {
        GameScene game = new GameScene(gameCode);
        game.setOnLogoutHandle(() -> switchToLoginView(null));
        game.setOnGameWinHandle(() -> switchToWinView(gameCode));

        primaryStage.setTitle("GAME - SPACCA");
        primaryStage.setScene(game.getScene());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    private void createWinView(String gameCode) {
        WinnerScene winner = new WinnerScene(gameCode);
        winner.setOnBackHandle(() -> switchToTournamentLobbyView(winner.getMainFilePath()));
        winner.setOnHomeHandle(() -> switchToLoginView(null));

        primaryStage.setTitle("GAME WINNER - SPACCA");
        primaryStage.setScene(winner.getScene());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    private void createGameSetupView(boolean isTournament) {
        GameSetupScene gameSetup = new GameSetupScene(isTournament);
        gameSetup.setOnLogoutHandle(() -> switchToLoginView(gameSetup.getFileName()));

        String title = "";
        if(isTournament == false) { title = "SIMPLE MATCH SETUP - SPACCA"; }
        else { title = "TOURNAMENT SETUP - SPACCA"; }

        primaryStage.setTitle(title);
        primaryStage.setScene(gameSetup.getScene());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    private void createTournamentLobbyView(String gameCode) {
        TournamentLobby trLobby = new TournamentLobby(gameCode);
        trLobby.setOnLogoutHandle(() -> switchToLoginView(null));
        trLobby.setOnStartGameHandle(() -> switchToGameView(trLobby.getFullChildPath()));

        primaryStage.setTitle("TOURNAMENT " + gameCode + " - SPACCA");
        primaryStage.setScene(trLobby.getScene());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    private void createLeaderboardView() {
        LeaderboardScene lead = new LeaderboardScene();
        lead.setOnLogoutHandle(() -> switchToLoginView(null));

        primaryStage.setTitle("LEADERBOARD - SPACCA");
        primaryStage.setScene(lead.getScene());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    private void createInstructionView() {
        InstructionScene instruction = new InstructionScene();
        instruction.setOnGoBackHomeHandler(() -> switchToLoginView(null));

        primaryStage.setTitle("INSTRUCTIONS - SPACCA");
        primaryStage.setScene(instruction.getScene());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    private void createUserSceneView() {
        UserScene user = new UserScene();
        user.setOnGoBackAdminHandler(() -> switchToHomeView());

        primaryStage.setTitle("MANAGE USER - SPACCA");
        primaryStage.setScene(user.getScene());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }

    private void switchToHomeView() {
        createHomeView();
    }

    private void switchToLoginView(String fileCode) {
        createLoginView(fileCode);
    }

    private void switchToGameView(String gameCode) {
        createGameView(gameCode);
    }

    private void switchToWinView(String gameCode) {
        createWinView(gameCode);
    }

    private void switchToGameSetupView(boolean isTournament) {
        createGameSetupView(isTournament);
    }

    private void switchToTournamentLobbyView(String gameCode) {
        createTournamentLobbyView(gameCode);
    }

    private void switchToLeaderBoardView() {
        createLeaderboardView();
    }

    private void switchToInstructionView() {
        createInstructionView();
    }

    private void switchToUserSceneView() {
        createUserSceneView();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

can somebody help me fix this issue?

i tried to reinsatll javafx22 SDK but still doesn't work

Comment: When you get exception messages, it usually means there is something wrong in your code. Reinstalling compiler or library components will rarely help. In the above list the key message would appear to be: *Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null*. So you need to trace back to try and find out why that call is not returning a valid reference.

Comment: The root cause is `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null at org.example.LoginScene.<init>(LoginScene.java:48)`  That last part says the problem is at line 48 of LoginScene.java.  Edit your question and show us LoginScene.java.  My guess is that you passed an incorrect URL to ClassLoader.getResource.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/6395627)

Comment: Also see https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/